# Dynamic_Cast in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

With proper OOD, its rarely that I have to use dynamic_cast, but I am using it with the following example. Is this the correct **approach**? The idea of the code that Long and Double classes are Numerics, and I nned to be able to add Numerics including mixture of Double and Long like shown in main().

```
class Numeric{
  virtual Numeric& (const Numeric& num)=0;
 }

class Double: public Numeric{
   double data;
   Numeric& operator+(const Numeric& num){
     //if Double type
     if(Double* d = dynamic_cast<Double *>(num)){
         return Double(data+(Double &)num.data);
       }
     else{  //must be Long
         return (doLongDoubleMath());
       }
    }
 }
 class Long: public Numeric{
  long data;
   Numeric& operator+(const Numeric& num){
   }
 }

  int main(){
    Numeric &n1 = Double(1.1);
    Numeric &n2 = Long(10);
    Numeric &result = n1+n2;

   return 0;
   }
```

I want to be able to mix different types, like add Double and Long..etc, Is Dynamic_cast the right way to go about this, or can you think of better way?

Comment: Are you sure that your code compiles? Try with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  .... Your second line looks suspicious to me...

Comment: you need to provide operator+ overload. Without that how can you call addition operation on user defined objects?

Comment: But you should make that a real code.

Comment: I am sorry, which part doesn't look real?

Comment: The second line is `virtual Numeric& (const Numeric& num)=0;` I believe that does not compile, and I don't understand what you mean ... So please, edit your question till your code compiles. Also, why the references in `main`?

Comment: you also cast a reference into a pointer

Comment: Just an aside, "proper OOD" is nice, but with C++, not always the best "D" to go for. You *might* want to check whether a template class and e.g. [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_integer) could float your boat (better). Hard to say with pseudo code, really; it's hard to tell where your code does something different from what the POD types do *already*.

Comment: Why do you insist on compiling, It is very clear a polymorphism design with a Numeric object and two classes Double and Long that inherit it. The idea is to to be able to add Numerics, Long+Long, Double+Double, Long+Double, Double+Long. I  was wondering if there is a better way than using Dynamic_Cast to check for type when I add Double to Long and vice versa, thats all.

Comment: Look up "visitor pattern" and "double dispatch". Your particular case is problematic, you cannot return by reference and you cannot return by value, you *must* allocate dynamically and return a (suitably encapsulated) pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you need to be polymorphic on *two* objects instead of one. The dynamic cast is one way to solve this, but I think there is a better one: double dispatch:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;
class Base {
    public:
        virtual Base& operator+(const Base& other) = 0;

    protected:
        virtual Base& addTo(Foo& other) const = 0;
        virtual Base& addTo(Bar& other) const = 0;
}
class Foo : public Base {
    public:
        virtual Base& operator+(const Base& other) {
            return other.addTo(*this);
        }
}
...
```

Of course, that means that you have to write `N^2` `addTo()` functions, where `N` is the number of classes that you want to be able to add interchangeably. But it's the same count as `if(Foo& foo = dynamic_cast<Foo&>(other)) {...}`-clauses that you would need to write.

And the double dispatch is likely faster, because your `else if()` ladder will check the type of the other object several times, while the virtual function call will only once follow a vtable pointer to call the right function.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have already tried the double dispatch, which I assumed its "equivalent" to dynamic casting. The only thing I noticed with double dispatching is debating if I need to return a pointer or a ref with the 2nd dispatch functions, as I don't want the user to own any memory, so refs is probably the way to go.

Comment: The problem with returning a reference and returning a pointer is the same: the object that's returned must outlive the function call. That is, you cannot return a pointer/reference to a local variable. Whether you use a pointer or a reference is irrelevant.

Comment: But if I return a pointer, a pointer can be NULL, then the user will have to handle that, No?

Comment: Yes, if you want to declare that you are not returning `NULL`, return a reference. Your inner function of the double dispatch can do the same. However, in any case, you can't return `Double(data+(Double &)num.data)`, because that would return a reference/pointer to a temporary, which won't outlive the function call. Honestly, I think your best option is to just return the sum by value.

Comment: Yes, Understood. Thanks.

Comment: "I don't want the user to own any memory, so refs is probably the way to go." If it could possibly work this way nobody would need any pointers ever, dontchathink?

Comment: @cmaster Return an abstract type by value? I have a gut feeling that something could possibly nit work as expected here.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, yes, you are right, my bad. Of course, that would slice the object. That leaves only two possibilities: returning a `new` object and leaving it to the caller to destroy it, or reusing one of the arguments. Either approach does not work well with overloading operators. A third possibility would be that the class that overloads the operators is actually just a smart pointer to the `Numeric` class. These smart pointers could easily be passed/returned by value, and manage the `Numeric` objects as needed.

Comment: Interesting, because I was thinking returning the argument after I manipulate it, but I believe the argument needs to be const since number(arg) passed can't change. Smart Pointers it is.

Comment: So, you were thinking something along these lines provided this isn't using dispatch approach.                                                                                  shared_ptr<Numeric>& operator+(const Numeric& other)  {
  shared_ptr<Numeric> s(new Double(data + ((Double &)other).data));
  return s;
 }